# PowerShell Workflow - InlineScript Remoting

Tags: powershell, workflow, powershell-remoting

How can you use PowerShell workflows to interact with Exchange Online via remote PowerShell and take advantage of the workflow features such as parallel foreach, retries, etc.?

#

I could never find specific examples of this and finally got it working so I wanted to share.  This PowerShell workflow allows you to query Exchange Online (could be Exchange on-premises as well) in parallel, automatically retries on error and throttles itself.

Hopefully this is of benefit to others (and is an appropriate way to post a question/answer), if you have other examples of PowerShell workflows using remoting I would love to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
workflow Test-ExchangeQuery {
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    #>
    Param
    (
        # Username of account
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string[]]
        $Identity,

        # Exchange / AD Credentials
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        $Credential
    )

    Set-PSWorkFlowData -PSAllowRedirection $true

    ForEach -Parallel -ThrottleLimit (2) ($user in $Identity) {
        InlineScript {
            Get-Mailbox -Identity $using:user | Select-Object Name, PrimarySmtpAddress
        } -DisplayName "Querying Exchange" `
            -PSCredential $Credential `
            -PSConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" `
            -PSConfigurationName "Microsoft.Exchange" `
            -PSComputerName $null `
            -PSAuthentication Basic `
            -PSConnectionRetryCount 3 `
    }
}
```